# Beamer background and text

Tags: beamer, color, backgrounds, themes

I have provided a minimal example of the output I have shown below:

```
\documentclass [compress]{beamer}
\newcommand\Fontvi{\fontsize{6}{7.2}\selectfont}
\usepackage{remreset}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\definecolor{ForestGreen}{RGB}{60, 140, 60}
\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{fg=white,bg=ForestGreen}
\beamersetuncovermixins{\opaqueness<1>{35}}{\opaqueness<2->{50}}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
\leavevmode%
\hbox{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{palette primary}%
\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{\hskip0pt plus1filll}
\end{beamercolorbox}%
}
}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]
\setbeamercovered{invisible}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\useoutertheme[footline=empty,subsection=false]{miniframes}

\begin{document}
\title{Multisource data analysis}  
\author{Author name} 
\institute{Biochemistry}
\date{\today} 
\begin{frame}[plain]
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\section{Motivation} 

\begin{frame} \frametitle {biofuel production}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.30]{/home/Documents/mot1.png} 
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

What am trying to do is to add the below logo as titleslide beamer footline for the entire paperwidth

[image]

And I defined the following before the beginning of the document:

```
\pgfdeclareimage[width=\paperwidth]{mybackground}{/home/Documents/ta.jpg}

\setbeamertemplate{title page}{

   \begin{picture}(0,0)

        \put(-30,-163){%
           \pgfuseimage{mybackground}
        }

        \put(0,-110.7){%

            \begin{minipage}[b][50mm][t]{200mm}

                \usebeamertemplate {title}{\inserttitle\par}
                \usebeamercolor{author}{\insertauthor\par}
                \usebeamercolor{institute}{\insertinstitute\par}
                \usebeamercolor{date}{\insertdate\par}
            \end{minipage}
        }

        \end{picture}

   }
```

and got this in the end

[image]

But the problem here is I lose the green box I defined for the title. I would like to have it similar to the first image with just the logo added to the bottom. In addition for the second slide I am unable to change the blue box in the headline to green. I would like to have similar forest green boxes for all the slide headlines.

Comment: Instead of `\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{fg=white,bg=ForestGreen}` write `\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=ForestGreen}` to change header colors. Almost all beamer color themes are based on this `structure` color and changing it, all other colors change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest is to add the picture as a background to the slides, and then clearing it after the title slide:

```
\setbeamertemplate{background}{%
\put(0,-265){%
           \pgfuseimage{mybackground}
}
}
```

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass [compress]{beamer}
\newcommand\Fontvi{\fontsize{6}{7.2}\selectfont}
\usepackage{remreset}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\definecolor{ForestGreen}{RGB}{60, 140, 60}
\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{fg=white,bg=ForestGreen}
\beamersetuncovermixins{\opaqueness<1>{35}}{\opaqueness<2->{50}}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
\leavevmode%
\hbox{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{palette primary}%
\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{\hskip0pt plus1filll}
\end{beamercolorbox}%
}
}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]
\setbeamercovered{invisible}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\useoutertheme[footline=empty,subsection=false]{miniframes}

 %%-------------------------------------
 %% here declare the background
\pgfdeclareimage[width=\paperwidth]{mybackground}{alaska.jpg}
\setbeamertemplate{background}{%
\put(0,-265){%
           \pgfuseimage{mybackground}
}
}
%%-------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\title{Multisource data analysis}
\author{Author name}
\institute{Biochemistry}
\date{\today}
\begin{frame}[plain]
\titlepage
\end{frame}
%%-------------------------------------
\setbeamertemplate{background}{}      %% clear background after title slide
%%-------------------------------------
\section{Motivation}
\begin{frame} 
\frametitle {biofuel production}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.30]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That works thanks! Could you also please point out why am unable to change the headline of the second slide to Forest Green. It remains blue!